# SwiftUI List exposed white background in landscape orientation

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui

I have a `viewController` that allows the user to select their choice of notification sounds. The list is presented by the SwiftUI with the name of each sound and a preview button. All is fine in portrait mode:

[image]

But in landscape the edges of the screen show white:

[image]

Here's my SwiftUI code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SoundItem: Hashable {
  var name: String
  var pdSelection: Bool = false
  var pESelection: Bool = false
  var advanceAlertSelection: Bool = false
}

struct SoundListItem: View {

  var item: SoundItem
  var delegate: NotificationsSoundControllerViewController?

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Image(item.pdSelection ? "post-dose-select" : "post-dose-unselect")
        .onTapGesture {
          if let d = self.delegate {
            d.selectPDSound(name: self.item.name) // defined in the protocol of the preferences view controller for updating the user prefs.
          }
      }
      Spacer()
      Text(item.name.localizedCapitalized).font(Font.custom("Exo2-SemiBold", size: 20.0)).foregroundColor(item.advanceAlertSelection ? Color.green : Color.white)
      .onTapGesture {
          if let d = self.delegate {
            d.selectAdvanceSound(name: self.item.name) // defined in the protocol of the preferences view controller for updating the user prefs.
          }
      }
      Spacer()
      Image(systemName: "play.fill")
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .onTapGesture {
          if let d = self.delegate {
            d.playPreviewSound(name: self.item.name)
          }
      }.padding(.trailing, 40.0)
      Image(item.preExpirySelection ? "pre-expiry-select" : "pre-expiry-unselect")
      .onTapGesture {
          if let d = self.delegate {
            d.selectPESound(name: self.item.name) // defined in the protocol of the preferences view controller for updating the user prefs.
          }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ListHeading: View {

  let headingFont: Font = Font.custom("Exo2-SemiBold", size: 12.0)
  var body: some View {
    HStack{
      Text("Post").font(headingFont).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
      Spacer()
      Text("Click name for advance alert").font(headingFont).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
      Spacer()
      Spacer()
      Text("Pre").font(headingFont).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
    }
  }
}

struct NotificationSoundsSUIView: View {

  @ObservedObject var noteController: NotificationsSoundControllerViewController

  init(){
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
    noteController = NotificationsSoundControllerViewController()
  }

  var body: some View {
    Section(header: ListHeading()) {
      List {
        ForEach (self.noteController.sounds, id: \.self) { sound in
          SoundListItem(item: sound, delegate: self.noteController).listRowBackground(Color.black)
        }.background(Color.black)
  }.listRowBackground(Color.black)
    }
  }
}

struct NotificationSoundsSUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NotificationSoundsSUIView()
  }
}
```

And it's presented in the `viewController` with this:

```
var listView = NotificationSoundsSUIView() // See above code 
listView.noteController = self //pass over data for display by referencing this viewController
let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: listView)

childView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
childView.view.frame = view.frame
view.addSubview(childView.view)
view.sendSubviewToBack(childView.view)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
childView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

How can I force the entire background of the screen to remain black?

Comment: You need to set your constraints to `.super` not to the `.safeArea`. The safe area is for devices with notches or non-home-button devices.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your constraints in UIViewController set correctly here is to be done in SwiftUI part

```
Section(header: ListHeading()) {
      List {
        ForEach (self.noteController.sounds, id: \.self) { sound in
          SoundListItem(item: sound, delegate: self.noteController).listRowBackground(Color.black)
        }.background(Color.black)
  }.listRowBackground(Color.black)
}.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing]) // << here !!
```

Comment: Thanks. That does indeed make the list item fill the landscape width, but unfortunately, it puts it under the camera notch.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on an answer that seems to solve the problem and also maintain the safe area clearence of the list. I changed the SwiftUI view's `body` to:

```
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Spacer() // < Inserted a spacer
      VStack { // < Using a HStack causes the list headings to appear to the left of the list itself
        Section(header: ListHeading()) {
          List {
            ForEach (self.noteController.sounds, id: \.self) { sound in
              SoundListItem(item: sound, delegate: self.noteController).listRowBackground(Color.black)
            }.background(Color.black)
          }.listRowBackground(Color.black)
        }
      }
      Spacer() // < Inserted a spacer
    }
  }
}
```